# Convert string into integer in bash script - "Leading Zero" number error

Tags: bash

In a text file, test.txt, I have the next information:

```
sl-gs5 desconnected Wed Oct 10 08:00:01 EDT 2012 1001
```

I want to extract the hour of the event by the next command line:

```
hour=$(grep -n sl-gs5 test.txt | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f6 | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')
```

and I got "08". When I try to add 1,

```
 14 echo $((hour+1))
```

I receive the next error message:

```
./test2.sh: line 14: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

If variables in Bash are untyped, why?

Comment: The leading 0 is leading to bash trying to interpret your number as an octal number, but octal numbers are 0-7, and 8 is thus an invalid token.

Comment: This error comes from "leading zero" error AKA any 0 digit that comes before the first non-zero representation in bash. examples ( for example 01 ,002 , 0000003 etc... )

Answer (score 120):

See *ARITHMETIC EVALUATION* in `man bash`:

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.

You can remove the leading zero by *parameter expansion*:

```
hour=${hour#0}
```

or force base-10 interpretation:

```
$((10#$hour + 1))
```

Comment: You can also force the base-10 interpretation: `$((10#$hour+1))`.

Comment: This is not working for my bash and negative numbers: `lat=-048 ; latd=${lat#0} ; echo $latd ; echo $((latd-1))` gives me `-048` and then the same error.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: Of course, as `#0` removes zero from the start of the string, and there's a `-` instead. Use `shopt -s extglob ; latd=${latd#?(-)0}`.

Comment: What's funny is that the $((10#$hour + 1)) does not work either for negative numbers. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with that is that you get the absolute value (in the example, `47` instead of `-49`. It seems this needs a longer oneliner maybe with `sed`,`bc` or something that I wanted to avoid since mine is inside a big loop. I hate this octal thing `bash` do. It should be possible to configure it with a `shopt`.

Comment: Numbers with an optional leading `+` or `-` can be handled with `$((${hour%%[^-+]*}10#${hour#[-+]}))`

Answer (score 17):

what I'd call a hack, but given that you're only processing hour values, you can do

```
 hour=08
 echo $(( ${hour#0} +1 ))
 9
 hour=10 
 echo $(( ${hour#0} +1))
 11
```

with little risk.

IHTH.

Answer (score 10):

You could also use `bc`

```
hour=8
result=$(echo "$hour + 1" | bc)
echo $result
9
```

Comment: It worked for me so +1 however, I was looking for some simple soln like result=int("$hour + 1")

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easy way, albeit not the prettiest way to get an int value for a string.

```
hour=`expr $hour + 0`
```

Example

```
bash-3.2$ hour="08"
bash-3.2$ hour=`expr $hour + 0`
bash-3.2$ echo $hour
8
```

Comment: This just produces the string `08+0`

Comment: what shell are you using @JimGarrison

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**In Short:** In order to deal with "**Leading Zero**" numbers (any 0 digit that comes before the first non-zero) in bash
 - Use `bc` An arbitrary precision calculator language

Example:

```
a="000001"
b=$(echo $a | bc)
echo $b
```

> Output: 1

From Bash manual:

> "bc  is  a language that supports arbitrary precision numbers with interactive execution
>          of statements.  There are some similarities in the syntax to  the  C  programming  lan-
>          guage.  A standard math library is available by command line option.  If requested, the
>          math library is defined before processing any files.  bc starts by processing code from
>          all  the  files  listed  on the command line in the order listed.  After all files have
>          been processed, bc reads from the standard input.  All code is executed as it is  read.
>          (If  a file contains a command to halt the processor, bc will never read from the standard input.)"

Answer (score 2):

Since hours are always positive, and always 2 digits, you can set a 1 in front of it and subtract 100:

```
echo $((1$hour+1-100))
```

which is equivalent to

```
echo $((1$hour-99))
```

Be sure to comment such gymnastics. :)

Answer (score 1):

The leading 0 is leading to bash trying to interpret your number as an octal number, but octal numbers are 0-7, and 8 is thus an invalid token.

If I were you, I would add some logic to remove a leading 0, add one, and re-add the leading 0 if the result is < 10.

Answer (score 1):

How about sed?

```
hour=`echo $hour|sed -e "s/^0*//g"`
```