# Value too Great for Base (error token is "080"

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am extracting information from a text file specifically **"FEW080"**

However, when running my script this is the error I receive Value too Great for Base (error token is "080"
Since there is a leading zero I am assuming it is taking it as octal but I want to suppress any leading zeros

```
fewClouds=$( egrep -o '\sFEW[0-9]{3}\s' metar.txt | cut -c5-7 ) 

if [ -n "$fewClouds" ]; then
fewClouds=$(($( egrep -o '\sFEW[0-9]{3}\s' metar.txt | cut -c5-7) *100))

printf "\nFew Clouds at %s feet" $fewClouds
fi
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777597/value-too-great-for-base-error-token-is-08 answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly sure how I would implement that solution within my code, tried varying ways still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 5):

In bash you can specify a base in the arithmetic expansions.

Also, as you're already using `grep -o` then you should use `grep -oP` with a look-behind and a look-ahead:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if fewClouds=$(grep -oP '(?<=\sFEW)[0-9]{3}(?=\s)' metar.txt)
then
    fewClouds=$(( 10#$fewClouds * 100 ))

    printf "\nFew Clouds at %s feet" "$fewClouds"
fi
```

Comment: Note that not all versions of `grep` having `-o` are guaranteed to also have `-P` -- linking libpcre is a separate compile-time option in GNU grep.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. Now that you said it, it does make sense that pcre support is optional