# Why am I not getting an output even though my code should technically have an output

Tags: bash, csv, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a code where an organization is organizing an virtual event with a raffle and is identifying a subset of the attendees
that born in a certain month. Therefore, the event organizer needs to list only eligible members. The
members’ information is given in a CSV file, and the record format in this data file is as follow:

```
firstName,lastName,YYYYMMDD
```

However, the year can either be in a Gregorian calendar, where the current year is 2022, or a Buddhist calendar, where the current year is 2565.

Comment: Use `set -x` to enable debug tracing of the script. Or add more print statements, but either way you should do some debugging at this stage.

Comment: please update the question with the expected output (corresponding to the provided sample input)

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Try `awk` which is the tool for this job

Comment: Don't use a shell read loop for this, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), just use an awk script as already suggested.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with the code in the question, including syntax errors, logic errors, and some stylistic issues (e.g. use of magic numbers, unnecessary repetition).  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code attempts to fix most of them:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

month=$1
csvfile=$2

gregorian_year=$(date '+%Y')
buddhist_year=$((gregorian_year + 542))

months=( '' January February March April May June
            July August September October November December )

while IFS=, read -r forename surname yyyymmdd ; do
    birth_year=${yyyymmdd:0:4}
    birth_month=${months[10#${yyyymmdd:4:2}]}

    age=$(( (birth_year > gregorian_year)
            ? (buddhist_year - birth_year)
            : (gregorian_year - birth_year) ))

    if [[ $birth_month == "$month" ]] && (( age > 18 && age < 100 )); then
        printf '%s,%s,%s\n' "$forename" "$surname" "$yyyymmdd"
    fi
done < "$csvfile"
```

- The `10#` in `birth_month=${months[10#${yyyymmdd:4:2}]}` forces the month number to be treated as a decimal (base 10) number.  Otherwise `08` and `09` will cause errors as invalid octal numbers.  See [Value too great for base (error token is "08")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24777597/4154375).
- Note that the code does not produce any output given the arguments `May guest.csv` and the `guest.csv` contents given in the question because the only person born in May is only 7 years old.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two reasons why the script doesn't show anything with the example data.

1. There is a bug in the date extraction `d="${line##,}`, as this just tries to remove a leading comma. The line should be:

```bash
d="${line##*,}"
```

2. There is a logic error when computing age: you always subtract the birth year from the current Gregorian year. This way, the only May-born person in your data file is 2023-2566 = -535 years old, which is not between 18 and 100. You need a way to tell which calendar is being used and compute the age accordingly.

Finally, I'm not sure that `echo "%s\n" "$line"` is going to give the intended output. You probably confused `echo` and `printf`.