# Removing Leading 0 from a number causes value to change

Tags: bash

I do not understand what is happening here, based on [Convert string into integer in bash script - "Leading Zero" number error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821715/convert-string-into-integer-in-bash-script-leading-zero-number-error/12821845#12821845), I am able to convert the string into integer. I can even do addition. However, when I compare the numbers it gives me the wrong comparison. Refer to example below

Here's an example

```
array=(02 08 10 11 23 52)

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5
    do
        if [[ ${array[i]#0} > 15 ]]
        then
            echo "${array[i]#0} is greater than 15"
        else
            echo "${array[i]#0} is less than 15"
        fi
done
```

Output

```
2 is greater than 15
8 is greater than 15
10 is less than 15
11 is less than 15
23 is greater than 15
52 is greater than 15
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `>` with `-gt` for arithmetic tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare numbers in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/how-can-i-compare-numbers-in-bash) - the leading `0` isn't the problem here, since your values don't change in octal; it's all about the position of "15" versus "2" in a dictionary-style string ordering.

Comment: @dawg yep that helped a lot, I never knew there was so much difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change `[[ ]]` to `(( ))` to use `>` or change the operator to `-gt` to do integer comparisons inside of `[[ ]]`

First:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(02 08 10 11 23 52)

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5
do
    if (( ${array[i]#0} > 15 ))
    then
        echo "${array[i]#0} is greater than 15"
    else
        echo "${array[i]#0} is less than 15"
    fi
done
```

Second:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(02 08 10 11 23 52)

for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5
do
    if [[ ${array[i]#0} -gt 15 ]]
    then
        echo "${array[i]#0} is greater than 15"
    else
        echo "${array[i]#0} is less than 15"
    fi
done
```

If you use `< > ==` inside of `[ ]` or `[[ ]]` is a [string comparison operator](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html). The string `"02"` is in fact less than the string `"15"`:

```
% [[ 02 > 15 ]]; echo $?
1                        # '1' means false and '0' means true
```

BUT you are stripping the leading `"0"` with `#0`:

```
% s="02"
% echo ${s#0}
2
```

So now you are comparing the STRING `"2"` to the STRING `"15"`:

```
% [[ 2 > 15 ]]; echo $?
0 
% [[ ${s#0} > 15 ]]; echo $?
0
```

Which give the surprising result you are seeing...

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40431336/298607) for an expanded set of examples.