# Bash-Script: How to test if hour number is even?

Tags: bash, shell

In a bash script (run every 30min), I want to do an action every even hour (and minutes 0), so I want to test the hour number if it's an even number or not.
So I use this:

```bash
        HEURE=$(date +"%H")
        MINUTES=$(date +"%M")
        HEURE_PAIRE=""
        MINUTES_ZERO=""
        [[ $((HEURE % 2)) -eq 0 ]] && HEURE_PAIRE="OUI" || HEURE_PAIRE="NON"
        [[ $MINUTES -eq 0 ]] && MINUTES_ZERO="OUI" || MINUTES_ZERO="NON"
        if [[ "${HEURE_PAIRE}" == "OUI" ]] && [[ "MINUTES_ZERO" == "OUI" ]]; then
            # My code
        fi
```

But I get an error for this line (n°170 in my script) `[[ $((HEURE % 2)) -eq 0 ]] && HEURE_PAIRE="OUI" || HEURE_PAIRE="NON"` when it was `08:00`, `08:30`, `09:00`, `09:30`, but not for `10:00` or `10:30`. See the error I get:

```
/volume4/docker/_Scripts-DOCKER/driver-pkgctl-r8152-restart-reload.sh: line 170: 08: value too great for base (error token is "07")
/volume4/docker/_Scripts-DOCKER/driver-pkgctl-r8152-restart-reload.sh: line 170: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
```

I expected to have it working like this:
For `08:00`, the `08%2` should return `0` as a result, proving hour is even.
For `09:00`, the `09%2` should return `1` as a result, proving hour isn't even.
Not having an error

I assume it's the `0` before the `8` or `9`... But I don't know how to fix this.

I found a workaround [with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12821845/17694638) by adding this:

```bash
HEURE=${HEURE#0}
```

It seems to be working.

My question: is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Corrected script:

forcing base 10¹:

```
#!/bin/bash

heure=10#$(date +"%H") minutes=10#$(date +"%M")
if (( heure % 2 == 0 && minutes == 0 )); then
    # My code
fi
```

---

Another way using `POSIX` *parameter expansions*

```
#!/bin/bash

heure=$(date +"%H") minutes=$(date +"%M")
if (( ${heure#0} % 2 == 0 && ${minutes#0} == 0 )); then
    # My code
fi
```

---

another way using `crontab`

```
*/30 * * * * /path/to/script
```

---

[Don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

---

`((...))` and `$((...))` are arithmetic commands, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

---

¹
In arithmetic operations with `bash`, is there's a leading `0` like `08`, it's treated as an octal number. To force base10, I use `10#` prefix on hour and minutes

---

No need to quote in `[[ ... ]]` syntax, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Comment: Thanks for your help. I learned something today :)
May I submit the whole script to review?

Comment: Don't know what kind of review do you mean

Comment: @MilesTEG: See: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Simplified for code review

Comment: Just to check if it should be improved. But first of all, I need to lowercase my variables names ^^
Your correct script isn't working.
The time format in the date commands isn't good. It should be:
```bash
heure=10#$(date +"%H")
minutes=10#$(date +"%M")
```
Because with the lowercase h and m, I get this (with faketime):
```bash
faketime '08:00:00' ./test.sh
dim. 16 avril 2023 08:00:00 CEST
heure is : 10#avril
minutes is : 10#04
./test.sh: ligne 12: ((: 10#avril : valeur trop grande pour la base (le symbole erroné est « 10#avril »)
```
Line 12 is the one with the modulo test.

Comment: It's a typo, sorry, I correct

Comment: Another question linked to the previous one.
I have this test : `if [[ "${gotify_always}" == "OUI" ]] || [ ${gotify_priority} -eq ${gotify_priority_error} ] || [ ${gotify_priority} -eq ${gotify_priority_fail} ] || { [ ${gotify_priority} -eq ${gotify_priority_success} ] && [[ "${heure_paire}" == "oui" ]] && [[ "${minutes_zero}" == "oui" ]]; }; then
`.
Is it correct ?
PS : all other variables are string variables.

Comment: Post another question. But mostly, can be simplified

Comment: TIL that `#` in that context isn't the start of a comment. Not sure why it isn't but thanks!

Comment: New question isn't possible right now, I'm on a question ban... And I can't improve my first one as it was badly asked and I don't really remember what I wanted to ask.
PS : for the cron job possibility, I already put my script in the task scheduler of DSM (Synology NAS). So, I think, it's already in a cron job for every 30 minutes.
My script is to be executed every 30min, but only every 2h 00min, it will send a gotify notification, or if there is an error or a fail.

Comment: @EdMorton `#` has to be the first character of a word to signify a comment. See rules 7, 8 and 9: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03

Comment: @EdMorton I use a sort of 'cast' to avoid 'bash' to see e.x. 08 as octal. `10#08` is 'casted'  in base 10

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method without using arithmetic expressions:

```
#!/bin/bash

hm=$(date +%H%M)
if [[ $hm = ?[02468]00 ]]; then
    # do stuff
fi
```

or, in POSIX shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

hm=$(date +%H%M)
case $hm in
    ?[02468]00) do_stuff ;;
esac
```

or, with Bash arithmetic in a single operation:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( 10#$(date +%H%M) % 200 == 0 )); then
        echo "It is time" 
fi
```

Comment: Your solutions are similar to those of @jhnc .
I like the one for bash. It seems efficient.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to do what I want, and in a way I can understand :)

Comment: @m-nejat-aydin : Third method is working.
Can you explain, please?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the base is a good method for bash.

For POSIX shells that don't support that, there are other options.

**Prefix with a non-zero digit:**

```
heure=$(date +1%H)
...
```

**Strip the leading zero:**

```
heure=$(date +%H)
heure=${heure#0}
...
```

**Compare textually:**

```
heure=$(date +%H)
...
case $heure in ?[02468]) ... ;; esac
...
```

Comment: Your second proposition is the one I used before @gilles-quénot give the first answer.
Does your second proposition works for 13h, 14h... 23h ? I live in France where time is on 24 hours, not 12h AM/PM.

Comment: Simple way to find out is to try it: eg. `h=02; echo ${h#0}; h=14; echo ${h#0}`

Comment: it works.
And what about the "Compare textually" method?

Comment: what happens when you try it?

Comment: I don’t take time to try it, not yet. But I always try to understand the command before using it. And here si don’t see what would happen with a 2 numbers hour like 13 ou 23…

Answer (score 0):

First this is bad:

```
HEURE=$(date +"%H")
MINUTES=$(date +"%M")
```

The time can switch e.g. from 10:59 to 11:00 in between. And then you get the wrong 10:00.

Use either

```
time=$( date +%H:%M )
HEURE="${time%:*}"
MINUTES="${time#*:}"
```

... or ...

```
time=$( date +%s )
HEURE=$( date -d@$time +%H )
MINUTES=$( date -d@$time +%M )
```

In both variants you get the time only once. In the second example you'll get the epoche-time and then calculates hour an minute from this time. Thew first example seems to be more efficient.

Then replace `[[ $((HEURE % 2)) -eq 0 ]]` by `(( !( 10#$HEURE % 2 )))` or `(( ( 10#$HEURE % 2 ) == 0 ))`. The prefix `10#` forces the evaluation as decimal number.

Last note: In general, use lower case letters or mixed case for local var names.

Comment: That’s a good point. Time can change a little , yes. But my script is launched by DSM (Synology Nas) at 00:00 and every 30 minutes after that. S I assume that it fille be launched at 00:00:00 or some (milli)seconds after. And that’s not a problem in the tests made here . But you have a point here . It is preferable to get hour and minutes at the same time . I’ll implement that . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In numeric context, strings starting with a zero are considered octal. Therefore, `08` is in error.

However, I wouldn't do artithmetic to test for your condition. Instead, I would do something like

```
if [[ $(date +%HM) == ?[02468]00 ]]
then
  ....
fi
```

Comment: That’s what @m-nejat-aydin answered before you. Is it like regex but for bash? Would you explain please how it work?

Comment: It's not a regex, but a glob-pattern. In `[[ E1 == E2 ]]`, E2 is treated as glob pattern and E1 is matched against it. Globbing syntax is explained in the section _Pathname Expansion_ in the bash man-page.Be careful: If E2 is quoted, pattern matching is disabled. You can also use regex matching (bash uses POSIX extended regular expression). In this case the syntax is `[[ E1 =~ E2 ]]`.